# Laravel 5.4 Eloquent multiple table query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hi I want to form a query in `laravel 5.4` eloquent for the following SQL:
`select A.*, concat(B.firstname, ' ', B.lastname) as clientname, C.category as category from payments A, clients B, categories C where A.client_id = B.id and A.category_id = C.id`

All the foreign keys are properly given and the models are also properly created.

My aim is to get all the master record name like `category`, `client name`, etc to come in the child table record set directly.

Comment: Have you tried something? Where is your code?

Comment: You can use raw expressions with laravel query builder, just paste your raw SQL query in. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 0):

Paste your row query in `DB::row()` and print data like following

```
$data= DB::row("select A.*, concat(B.firstname, ' ', B.lastname) as clientname, C.category as category from payments A, clients B, categories C where A.client_id = B.id and A.category_id = C.id")->get();

dd($data);
```

if your query is right and properly managed relation than its retrieve data

Answer (score 0):

If you already made `Models` than Why you don't use ORM?

Use Models,

```
payment::leftJoin('clients ','payments.client_id','=','clients.id')
->leftJoin('categories ','payments.category_id ','=','categories .id')->select(['payment.*','categories.category',DB::raw("CONCAT(clients.firstname,' ',clients.lastname) as clientname")])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
DB::table('payments')
->select('payments.*',DB::raw('CONCAT(clients.firstname," ",clients.lastname) as clientname'),categories.category)
->join('clients','clients.id','=','payments.client_id')
->join('categories','categories.id','=','payments.category_id')
->get();
```

Hope this help for you !!!